# Does AWS Cognito support auto provisioning with Azure Ad as external Idp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to implement Auto-Provisioing on Azure Ad with AWS Cognito. The auto provisioning on the Azure is asking for a tenant url and I am using this for it. https://.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse. But Azure says it cannot establish a connection due to invalid creds. Please confirm if the url I am using is correct and also if Azure auto provisioning is possible with AWS cognito?

Comment: you have the extra unneccessary (.) in front of the auth

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with AWS Single Sign-on as it provides support for the System for Cross-domain Identity Management (SCIM).  However, this is an additional step after setting up your Identity Provider.

AWS Cognito does support external Identity Providers for authentication, but can't see any support for SCIM.  The SCIM endpoint is what is needed for the tenant URL.  So, not I don't think Cognito supports auto provisioning... be great if it did though.